# Get child elements of XML with XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have following XML:

```
<UpsHistory>
 <UpsSettings>
  <Filename>modbusevent.xml</Filename>
  <FileDate>04.02.1970</FileDate>
  <FileTime>00:05:39</FileTime>
  <Type>ENERTRONIC I 3-3 20kVA</Type>
  <Location></Location>
  <Phases>3</Phases>
  <UpsContact>
   <Company></Company>
   <Department></Department>
   <Contact></Contact>
   <City></City>
   <Street></Street>
   <Phone></Phone>
  </UpsContact>
 </UpsSettings>
 <UpsData id="1">
  <Date>09.08.2012</Date>
  <Time>12:05:53.52</Time>
  <EventCode>574</EventCode>
  <EventState>A</EventState>
  <EventText><![CDATA[IGBT - DRIVERBOARD FAILURE]]></EventText>
  <EventAction>/upsexe.cgi?cmd=2003&amp;p1=574&amp;reload=/mbevents.cgi&amp;wait=5</EventAction>
 </UpsData>
 <UpsData id="2">
  <Date>09.08.2012</Date>
  <Time>11:23:08.88</Time>
  <EventCode>606</EventCode>
  <EventState>E</EventState>
  <EventText><![CDATA[BYPASS VOLTAGE FAILURE]]></EventText>
  <EventAction>/upsexe.cgi?cmd=2003&amp;p1=606&amp;reload=/mbevents.cgi&amp;wait=5</EventAction>
 </UpsData>
 <UpsData id="3">
  <Date>09.08.2012</Date>
  <Time>11:23:07.06</Time>
  <EventCode>1000</EventCode>
  <EventState>E</EventState>
  <EventText><![CDATA[CUSTOMER RELAY 1 ON]]></EventText>
  <EventAction>/upsexe.cgi?cmd=2003&amp;p1=1000&amp;reload=/mbevents.cgi&amp;wait=5</EventAction>
 </UpsData>
 <UpsData id="4">
  <Date>09.08.2012</Date>
  <Time>11:23:06.97</Time>
  <EventCode>1003</EventCode>
  <EventState>E</EventState>
  <EventText><![CDATA[CUSTOMER RELAY 2 OFF]]></EventText>
  <EventAction>/upsexe.cgi?cmd=2003&amp;p1=1003&amp;reload=/mbevents.cgi&amp;wait=5</EventAction>
 </UpsData>

...

<UpsData id="602">
  <Date>08.09.2012</Date>
  <Time>11:06:13.84</Time>
  <EventCode>606</EventCode>
  <EventState>E</EventState>
  <EventText><![CDATA[BYPASS VOLTAGE FAILURE]]></EventText>
  <EventAction>/upsexe.cgi?cmd=2003&amp;p1=606&amp;reload=/mbevents.cgi&amp;wait=5</EventAction>
 </UpsData>
</UpsHistory>
```

I want to get all UpsData element with child element values, but I only UpsData element id:

Stream sw = CopyAndClose(response.GetResponseStream());

```
XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader(sw);
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                if (rdr.IsStartElement())
                                {
                                    if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                                    {
                                        if (rdr.Name == "UpsData")
                                        {
                                            rdr.MoveToAttribute("id");
                                            if (rdr.Name == "Date")
                                            {
                                                ConsoleInfo(rdr.Value);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

How I can get child elements values? Thanks!

Comment: If you know that the size of the XML input is going to be below a certain threshold, this seems like a job more suited to an `XmlDocument` than an `XmlReader`. The DOM methods would make this much easier.

Comment: How to get data of <Date> and other child elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument) or [XmlPathNagivator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator), consider an XPath. For example:

```
using System.Xml;

...

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in 
    xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("UpsData/@id[/*]"))
{
    // Do something, for example:
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Value: " + xmlNode.Value);
}
```

The XPath `"UpsData/@id[/*]"` says look for child nodes of called "UpsData" and an "id" attribute that have children and return the "id" attribute.

Comment: @amaranth It is faster but at significantly more development cost and time. If the XML files are small (a few hundred K or less), go for the XmlDocument or the XmlPathNagivator. As you know, the XmlReader is forward only, so you would need to find the UpsData element, grab the ID attribute value, then move forward to check if it has children.